# What is wrong with the installation of php oracle client oci8

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I tried all the procedures to install the PHP Oracle client.

1) I installed the Client version 8 and 32 bits.

2) I uncommented oci in php.ini

3) Restarted Wamp:

[image]

4) Not sure if really installed but I got the references in php.ini:

[image]

[image]

5) But still cannot connect:

[image]

Tyhanks for any help

**EDIT**

Found these errors in php log:
[16-Apr-2018 14:35:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_oci8.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

in Unknown on line 0

[16-Apr-2018 14:35:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_oci8_11g.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem was not to comment the ;extension=oci8_12c ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) tells you where you've gone wrong:

1. > 1) I installed the Client version 8 and 32 bits.

   You're using incompatible libraries. The first paragraph of the OCI8 [requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php) documentation states (emphasis mine):

   > The OCI8 1.4 extension is included with PHP 5.3, PHP 5.4 and PHP 5.5. It is also available from PECL. A newer OCI8 2.0 version is available only from PECL. **OCI8 1.4 requires Oracle 12c, 11g, 10g or 9iR2 client libraries** and will install on PHP 4.3.9 onwards. **OCI8 2.0 requires Oracle 12c, 11g or 10g client libraries** and will install on PHP 5.2 onwards.
2. > 2) I uncommented oci in php.ini

   Your screenshot shows you've enabled `php_oci8` and `php_oci8_11g`.  You should enable only one of the extensions, as stated in the OCI8 [installation](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php) documentation (again, emphasis mine):

   > When using Oracle 10gR2 client libraries on Windows, uncomment the php.ini line extension=php_oci8.dll. When using Oracle 11gR2 or later client libraries, uncomment extension=php_oci8_11g.dll or extension=php_oci8.dll. With Oracle 12c libraries use extension=php_oci8_12c.dll or extension=php_oci8_11g.dll or extension=php_oci8.dll. **Only one of these DLLs may be enabled at a time.**
3. > 4) Not sure if really installed but I got the references in php.ini:

   It's *installed* and *enabled*, but not *configured* correctly. Your screenshots show how PHP was compiled and the various code authors, not anything about your current configuration.

To get the extension working try the following:

1. Uninstall and remove all traces of the 'Client version 8'.
2. Install Oracle InstantClient 11g or 12c. This typically means simply extracting the .zip file to a folder, e.g. `c:\instantclient_12_1`.
3. On the InstantClient download page there is a link to the required VC++ runtime on the line after the InstantClient download link. Download and install it.
4. Update your `PATH` environment variable to include the location where you extracted the InstantClient files, e.g. `c:\instantclient_12_1`.
5. In `php.ini` enable either `php_oci8_11g.dll` **or** `php_oci8_12c.dll`.

You *might* need to reboot to ensure the `PATH` change is visible to the system.

Be aware that WAMP might include multiple `php.ini` files.  Make sure to edit the correct one.