# PHP projects not running from localhost on browser

Tags: php, yii, xampp, setup-project, configure

Following is the output displayed on browser on running any of the `Yii` project from localhost:

```
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

I have changed my system and the new system has newly installed windows 10, I have installed same xampp version over new system and moved `htdocs` folder in there. I also have configured `Fast CGI` in xampp to run two versions of php using same xampp just as I did in previous system's xampp. I have set the path variables for both php versions in system's environment paths. Also, uncommented the following lines from windows host file:

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

What else should I do to get the project run, what am I missing in setting up the system?

Answer (score 1):

I would fix these issues by following the steps below:

1. I would try to create a normal PHP script to see if Xampp is working fine.
2. If the PHP script runs fine then I would create a new Yii project from scratch and try to run it without making any changes to it.
3. If the Project doesn't work, it means the issue is with the Yii framework, then I would try to use an older version of the framework.
4. If an empty project works fine then I would migrate my original project source into the newly created Project one by one and try to find the bug on any script on the project.
5. I would surely find the bug until this step...

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar try viewing the page source using CTRL+U. You  mentioned that you configured Apache to use 2 PHP versions, if the PHP source can be seen it means Apache is not configured properly to interpret PHP code (via FastCGI). Please do include your Apache config in your post

Comment: I have uninstalled xamp and reinstalled and while accessing the project without FastCGI configurations as it is not necessary till now(it would needed to be configured some later),I get to know that issue was with oracle databases connection, some libraries of php were missing even though they were uncommented in php.ini file but they needed to be copied from ```oracle instant client``` directory to php ```apache/bin``` directory as mentioned in one of the answers in this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575207/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-c-xampp-php-ext-php-oci8-12c-dll